# Nothing happens when trying to update from 16.4 to 18.4 with software updater

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, do-release-upgrade

There are many similar questions on this site, still it is not clear to me which answer to these questions applies to my situation, so please forgive me for asking again.

After updating my software with the software updater I get the following message:

[image]

Today I pressed 'upgrade' (because I wanted to upgrade) and I was asked for my password (I wanted to screenshot this window also, but it seems impossible). After filling out my password and clicking 'authencicate' nothing happens.

Just nothing. The software updater is closed and ubuntu pretends nothing ever happens.

Following some internet sources I then tried to do it through the terminal:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

It produces an enormous amount of text (which I can paste here if it is useful), but the bottom line is not very reassuring:

`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.`

I tried `do-release-upgrade`

it answers:

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release
>
> Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

I have no idea how to do that. Put better: I thought I already did that. See the screenshot above: the software on this computer is up to date. What more can I do to 'install all available updates'?

Comment: Hey thanks, I hadn't seen that one. At least it answers what is the source of the problem!

Comment: I would suggest you to fresh install Ubuntu 20.04. That would be faster that updating twice, and you won't be left with redundant packages.

Comment: In your output: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and ` **`1 not upgraded`**

Comment: @user535733 yes, my question was about that. Why is it not upgraded? Not because I told him not to upgrade, I hope, because I thought I *did* tell the system to upgrade